# Construct a type

Tags: haskell

I have many type declarations:

```
module SumProduct where


  data GuessWhat = Chickenbutt deriving (Eq, Show)

  data Id a = MkId a deriving (Eq, Show)

  data Product a b = Product a b deriving (Eq, Show)

  data Sum a b = First a
                | Second b
                deriving (Eq, Show)

  data RecordProduct a b = RecordProduct { pfirst :: a , psecond :: b }
                          deriving (Eq, Show)


  newtype NumCow = NumCow Int deriving (Eq, Show)

  newtype NumPig = NumPig Int deriving (Eq, Show)

  data Farmhouse = Farmhouse NumCow NumPig deriving (Eq, Show)
  type Farmhouse' = Product NumCow NumPig


  newtype NumSheep = NumSheep Int deriving (Eq, Show)

  data BigFarmhouse = BigFarmhouse NumCow NumPig NumSheep deriving (Eq, Show) 
  type BigFarmhouse' = Product NumCow (Product NumPig NumSheep)

  type Name = String
  type Age = Int
  type LovesMud = Bool


  type PoundsOfWool = Int
  data CowInfo = CowInfo Name Age
                 deriving (Eq, Show)

  data PigInfo = PigInfo Name Age LovesMud deriving (Eq, Show)

  data SheepInfo = SheepInfo Name Age PoundsOfWool deriving (Eq, Show)


  data Animal = Cow CowInfo 
               | Pig PigInfo
               | Sheep SheepInfo
               deriving (Eq, Show)


  type Animal' = Sum CowInfo (Sum PigInfo SheepInfo)(Sum PigInfo SheepInfo)
```

And play around in the prelude with:

```
Prelude> let bess = First (CowInfo "Bess" 4) :: Animal'
Prelude> let elmer' = Second (SheepInfo "Elmer" 5 5)
```

How it comes, that the first becomes the type `bess :: Animal'` and the second `elmer' :: Sum a SheepInfo`?

Comment: This has nothing to do with your question, but you might like to know that you don't have to indent everything under the `module SumProduct where`. Just start the next line in column 0 and you can leave all your top-level declarations there.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

By default, Haskell infers the most general type that applies to the expression.

Here, you directly tell GHC what type `bess` is, so it just checks if the type you provided is valid, but allows it to be more specific than the most general type.

Since you explicitly tell GHC that `bess` has type `Animal'` by the `::` operator (it's a language construct, not an actual operator defined in the standard library), GHC already knows that `bess :: Animal'`. However, because you didn't provide any type for `elmer'`, GHC will find the most general type for you.

In this case, the most general type is `Sum a SheepInfo` because all GHC knows is that the `Second` constructor takes a `SheepInfo`, but has no idea of what `First` should take. Thus, it infers it to a type variable `a`.

Comment: What do you mean with the most  `most general type`, could you please provide an example?

Comment: What I call the most general type is the type that assumes the less information about the data. For example, when you type a number literal in Haskell, like `23`, it is inferred to `Num a => a`. This is why you can do `2 * 0.5`: `2`here is not an `Int`, but adapts to the right hand side number, which, in this case, is a floating point number.